# как заставить в хроме запускать' видео и аудио?

Tags: javascript, аудио, видео, web-audio

привет всем разработал скажем так маленькое приложения часы с фоновым видео и аудио,хочу  сделать так что бы при загрузки автоматически запускался воспроизведение на стороне клиента, в chrome не играет, в firefox можно настроить в ручную но не  каждый будет возиться с этим, помогите плиз решить эту задачу!

точнее как заставить с помощью javascript сделать autoplay или другими способами.

site : https://muradsky.github.io/myclock.github.io/
здесь исходники: https://github.com/MuradSky/myclock.github.io

Answer (score 0):

Так у вас не как не выйдет, так как идет нарушение Autoplay Policy Changes.

Для проигрывания музыки фоном, вам нужно дождаться действия со стороны пользователя, код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
    let nAudio = new Audio();
    let i = 0;
    let playList = new Array('Untitled1.mp3', 'unt2.mp3', 'Untitled.mp3');

    function onPlay () {
        let play = nAudio.play();
        if (typeof(play) != 'undefined') {
            play.catch(()=> {
                nAudio.muted = 1;
                let t = setTimeout(function () {
                    clearTimeout(t);
                    nAudio.muted = 0;
                    onPlay();
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
    }

    nAudio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', onPlay, true);
    nAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        i = ++i < playList.length ? i : 0;
        nAudio.src = playList[i];
        onPlay();
    }, true);

    try {
        nAudio.src = playList[i];
        nAudio.load();
    } catch (e) {}
```

Comment: благодарю,а видео тоже можно также поправить чтобы проигрывалась?

Comment: Запускайте видео с атрибутом muted="muted"

Comment: код замечательно сработал (в firefox) ,благодарю еще раз,но почему же не возможно воспроизвести аудио в chrome?

Comment: все сработал и в хроме,поздно загружается аудио.